# Null pointer exception in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, syntax, arrays

I try to get string that I don't want from string array by getting the array into for loop.

I try the following code but I get java.lang.NullPointerException and I don't know why.

Thank for helping.

```
String unWanted = new String[]{"","a","b","c"};

String[] temp = new String[unWanted.length-1];
int p = 0;
for (int k = 0; k < unWanted.length; k++){
    if(unWanted[k].equals("") == false)
    {
        temp[p] = unWanted[k];
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: At which line do you get your NPE?

Comment: except String unWanted[] = new String[]{"","a","b","c"}; seems to work

Comment: 1st line should start with `String[]` instead of `String`.

Comment: You get the NPE if you add some text in the first `String` in the array.

Answer (score 5):

The only error here is the `String` array declaration

```
String[] unWanted = new String[]{"","a","b","c"};
```

Comment: wait, could it be a typo ??

Comment: @PermGenError Even if it is, the code then doesn't produce an `NPE`

Comment: @rem thus, vote to close as not a real question :P

Answer (score 4):

`temp` has a length of 3 but you are inserting value at position 4 in your loop.

Comment: *"By accident"*, the OP's code is really inserting 3 values (empty string check...)

Comment: @LukasEder, I got it right away and I deleted my answer but I got 2 upvotes on this? LOL

Comment: People tend to agree, rather than to think... ;-)

Comment: @LukasEder so that's how you guys make reputation here. :)

Answer (score 2):

First change this line

```
String unWanted = new String[]{"","a","b","c"};
```

to

```
String[] unWanted = new String[]{"","a","b","c"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it even compiling ?

```
String unWanted = new String[]{"","a","b","c"};
```

change to

```
 String[] unWanted = new String[]{"","a","b","c"};
```

After the change there is no **NullPointerException** in my `console`. It works fine

Comment: @Shreyos Adikari thanks for the edit.